# I recently installed webpack and webpack-dev-server and getting this error on running it on localhost

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-cli

I recently installed webpack and webpack-dev-server and getting this error on running it from terminal.

error:
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'. These properties are valid: object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error is extremely clear: you use fields that are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Now webpack changed **contentBase** to **static**

To install `webpack-dev-server`

```
yarn add webpack-dev-server
```

or

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

then in `webpack.config.js` add this code

```
devServer: {
    static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
    },
    // hot: true,
}
```